# Why is my CameraX CameraView showing a blackscreen?

Tags: android, kotlin, camera, android-camerax

**I have been implementing CameraView for my app and it used to work few weeks ago, but now it is just showing a black screen, meaning the preview is not shown. As a result, it seems like the videos being recorded aren't being saved either.**

Can someone correct my code please?

**Manifest:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**build.gradle(app)**

```
 def camerax_version = "1.0.0-beta07"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-core:$camerax_version"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:$camerax_version"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:$camerax_version"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:1.0.0-alpha14"
```

**xml**

```
<androidx.camera.view.CameraView
        android:id="@+id/CameraView_cameraPreview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        app:captureMode="mixed"
        app:flash="auto"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.4"
        app:lensFacing="back"
        app:pinchToZoomEnabled="true"
        app:scaleType="fitCenter" />

**p.s: I have implemented this button in build.gradle**
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/Button_cameraRecord"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/camera_record_vector"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/CameraView_cameraPreview"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5" />
```

**Kotlin Activity**

```
package com.example.iambeta.camera

import android.Manifest
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.SystemClock
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.widget.SeekBar
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.camera.core.CameraSelector
import androidx.camera.core.VideoCapture
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import com.example.iambeta.R
import com.example.iambeta.storage.UploadActivity
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_camera.*
import java.io.File

//variables for requesting permission
private const val REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION = 101
var CAMERA_PERMISSION = Manifest.permission.CAMERA
var RECORD_AUDIO_PERMISSION = Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO
private val REQUIRED_PERMISSION = arrayOf(CAMERA_PERMISSION, RECORD_AUDIO_PERMISSION)
val TAG = Camera::class.java.simpleName

class Camera : AppCompatActivity() {

    //declaring variables for camera
    private var recordingStatus: recordingState? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera)

        //initializing variables for camera
        recordingStatus = recordingState.NOTRECORDING

        //if record button is clicked
        Button_cameraRecord.setOnClickListener{
            if(recordingStatus == recordingState.NOTRECORDING) {
                recordingStatus = recordingState.RECORDING
                startRecord()
            }else if(recordingStatus == recordingState.RECORDING){
                recordingStatus = recordingState.NOTRECORDING
                stopRecord()
            }
        }

    }

    //start recording
    fun startRecord(){
        //variable for storing the video/recording
        val fileStorage = "${System.currentTimeMillis()}.mp4"

        CameraView_cameraPreview.startRecording(File(externalMediaDirs.first(), fileStorage), ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this), object: VideoCapture.OnVideoSavedCallback {
            override fun onVideoSaved(file: File) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onVideoSaved $fileStorage")
            }

            override fun onError(videoCaptureError: Int, message: String, cause: Throwable?) {
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Recording Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                Log.e(TAG, "onError $videoCaptureError $message")
            }
        })
    }

    //stop recording
    fun stopRecord(){
        CameraView_cameraPreview.stopRecording()
        Toast.makeText(this, "Saved to /internalstorage/Android/media/...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        Log.i(TAG, "Video File Stopped")
    }

    //returns the result of requesting permission (i.e. failed obtaining permission)
    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION) {
            if (allPermissionsGranted()) {
                openCamera()
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permissions not granted by the user.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show()
                finish()
            }
        }
    }

    //checking if all permissions are granted
    private fun allPermissionsGranted(): Boolean {
        for (permission in REQUIRED_PERMISSION) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    this,
                    permission
                ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            ) {
                return false
            }
        }
        return true
    }

    //starting camera
    private fun openCamera(){
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            CameraView_cameraPreview.bindToLifecycle(this)
        }
    }

    //Enum class to see if the record button is recording or not
    enum class recordingState{
        RECORDING, NOTRECORDING
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        //check if all permission has been give, else request permission
        if(allPermissionsGranted()){
            openCamera()
        }else{
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, REQUIRED_PERMISSION, REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Update: I have fixed this with the following solution

In my function `openCamera()` I made it so that if the permission I'm checking for is **not** equal to permission granted, it will bind the preview. However, I could set it **equal** so that once it's granted, it can bind.
So instead of code looking like:

```
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            CameraView_cameraPreview.bindToLifecycle(this)
        }
```

It should look like:

```
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            CameraView_cameraPreview.bindToLifecycle(this)
        }
```